# Is there a connection in meaning between Psalm 103 and Luke 10:25-37?

Tags: psalms, parables

In Sarah Liberman's [music video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oW7kQyQbOhI) she sings Psalm 103 in Hebrew, but the video obviously portrays the parable of the Good Samaritan (Luke 10:25-37).  Is there a connection in meaning between these two?

Comment: It is a rather tenuous connection - Ps 103 only mentions "oppressed" once in V6.  The primary focus of Ps 103 is about the need of sinners of salvation not physical needs.  Therefore, I struggle to see a direct connection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I struggle to see any direct link between the parable of the Good Samaritan (Luke 10:25-37) and Ps 103.  The two are discussing completely different themes.

**The Good Samaritan**

The famous parable essentially teaches Christ's followers should be:

- personally responsible for anyone in need
- racially blind, ie, be non-racist and kind to all people

**Psalm 103**

By contrast, Ps 103 is a celebration and rehearsal of:

- God's forgiving character and that our sins are removed forever
- contrast to man's mortality
- God's redeeming nature for all sinners
- God's justice for the oppressed

Further, the parable of the Good Samaritan never quotes nor has any significant words/phrases in common with Ps 103.  The only tenuous connection between the two is the word "oppressed" which does not even occur (explicitly) in the Luke 10:25-37.  Even in this case, the "oppressed" are those who are needy in a legal sense and not a physical sense.

**CONCLUSION**

I do not see any direct link, either thematically or lingustically, between Ps 103 and Luke 10:25-37.

Comment: Thia seems to be the best answer.  The only way I see a strong connection is if one claims the Samaritan represents God, which would be a difficult connection for a Jew.

Comment: Not that I would make the connection, but this verse opens the possibility of saying the Samaritan represents Jesus: The Jews answered him, “Are we not right in saying that you are a Samaritan and have a demon?”
(John 8:48, ESV)

Comment: Robertson's Harmony of the Gospels puts John 8:48 before but near Luke 10:25-37. There is a question about Jesus' lack of response to being called a Samaritan. In a sense, maybe this was Jesus' response.

Comment: @PerryWebb - very good thought!

Comment: Found the question here https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/21366/is-jesus-the-good-samaritan

Comment: I posted an answer there: https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/21366/is-jesus-the-good-samaritan/79798#79798

Comment: Your answer remains the best, but I added an answer explaining how my question overthinks the connection.

Comment: I have no problem, theoretically, with Jesus telling a parable with a hated Samaritan representing God.  Nor do I stridently object to those who wish to make that at least one of the understandings of this exceptional parable, despite the fact that I do not believe it is the primary focus.  I believe it is an excellent parable for showing the short-sighted duplicity of the racially and theological biases of the Jews and sets us an example for racial indifference and sensitivity to those in need.

Answer (score 3):

There is a thematic connection in that both the Psalm and the parable emphasize God's compassion.

```
6 The Lord works righteousness
    and justice for all the oppressed...
8 The Lord is compassionate and gracious,
    slow to anger, abounding in steadfast love.,,
13 As a father has compassion on his children,
    so the Lord has compassion on those who fear him
```

17 the steadfast love of the Lord is from everlasting to everlasting...
18 to those who keep his covenant
and remember to do his commandments.

The Samaritan showed compassion for the man who had been nearly killed by robbers. In so doing  he followed the commandment of Moses (love your neighbor as yourself - Leviticus 19:18) more faithfully than either the priest or the Levite who put the letter of the law (not to touch a possibly dead body) ahead of its spirit. Like the symbol of the father in the parable of the Prodigal Son, the Samaritan also symbolized God's compassion for those who have been wronged, and indeed for all of God's children.

**So the parable and the psalm are connected through the theme of compassion and keeping the key commandment to love one's neighbor as oneself. This is probably what the artist had in mind by linking the two.**

Comment: This is a very good answer.  It was difficult to choose the best.

Answer (score 0):

While I gave a good hermeneutical question and there are hermeneutical answers here, our hermeneutics probably overthinks the connection Sarah Liberman made.  The setting of this song is COVID-19's impact on the world, and the need for healing mentally, spiritually, and economically, as well as physically.  Most songs written in English based on the 103 Psalm have the tone of celebration only.  Sarah restores the tune in the psalm of pleading for God's help.  While it's difficult to say the Good Samaritan represents God, he does show godly compassion in the parable.

What has also been noted about Psalm 103 is unlike many worship psalms, it is address to "my soul" rather than the LORD.  Thus, it has the sense of encouraging one to worship when not feeling like it.  Thus, it pleas for mercy.